# Reading varbinary column from database and displaying it in a pop window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a file uploader using html tags.

my `Data` column stores data in binary format in a column of datatype `varbinary(max)`.

I am able to successfully upload my file.

I am also making a grid which display the list of all my files with an icon next to it which when clicked will open a pop window and view me the file.

I have an `onclick` function

```
onclick = showDocument('" + dr["Id"] + "');
```

which I am accessing in the code behind through page method. This is my JS function in the aspx:

```
function showDocument(_id) {
     PageMethods.ShowDocument();
}
```

This function is pointing to my code behind function which is as follows.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void ShowDocument()
{
    byte[] bytes;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Data FROM FileUploader2", con))
        {
             using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if (reader.Read())
                 {
                     bytes = (byte[])reader["Data"];
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The above `ShowDocument` function is not really working. It just returns the bytes of my file and then nothing. Can someone edit the code above? Such that it reads `varbinary(max)` from my database and also display it in a popup window?

UPDATE:
Error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot download from an Ajax call directly, you could try by removing the static keyword from ShowDocument and the WebMethod attribute and use a simple link from your HTML.

Regarding the downloading, you have the contents of the file in your byte array and the content type and original filename stored in your database so it seems you have all the ingredients you need to send the response back to the browser, something like this:

```
public void ShowDocument()
{
    string filename = string.Empty;
    string contentType = string.Empty;
    byte[] bytes = null;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FileUploader2", con))
        {
             using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if (reader.Read())
                 {
                     filename = (string)reader["Name"];
                     contentType = (string)reader["ContentType"];
                     bytes = (byte[])reader["Data"];
                 }
             }
         }
     }
    Response.ContentType = contentType; 
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename); 
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
    Response.Flush(); 
}
```

Comment: And after reading the bytes, how to display it in a pop window? I have no idea.

Comment: You don't display it, you send it back to the browser and the browser will process the file according the content type; if you want to display contents from the files directly in the Website, that is another story and you would need to support specific content types and process them and display them individually. For example, it is not the same to read a text file or an docx as per your example.

Comment: How will I send it back to browser ? Can you give me an example code?

Comment: I already did, it is in my answer (the Response part) did you try it? ;-)

Comment: ok. It is giving me an error on response. An object reference is required for the non static field, method or property.System.Web.UI.page.response.get

Comment: I edited my question above and added the picture of error. Can you please check?

Comment: I need to see the whole class, but it seems you don't have access to he Response object, are you calling this from the page code behind?

Comment: Editing my question to add my whole code. I am calling this ShowDocument function from a javascript function through web method. The code is there in my question

Comment: Does not web methods have to be static?

Comment: You cannot download from a javascript call, you need to convert it to a regular server request

Comment: Ok. If I remove static, it gives me error on this line. Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); (use of unassigned local variable bytes)

Comment: Ok. Let me run now. I wil let you know

Comment: Now, It gives me error on my JS function showDocument(_id) { PageMethods.ShowDocument() } . (PageMethods is undefined)

Comment: I have PageMethods enabled already. Is it because we removed static keyword?

Comment: You can't use PageMethods to download, just create a link around your image tag and make it call the method in the code behind, like a regular ASP.NET control, not javascript.

Comment: Also, I added my static keyword back and changed Response.ContentType = contentType; to  System.Web.HttpContext.Current. Response.ContentType = contentType;  This way it works fine.

Comment: No, sorry I don't have time, I already gave you the solution, you should be able to make it work. Just add a regular asp.net control instead of using onclick in your image and it will work.